Error: "The schema must be one of the following: public" is showing when doing the Quickstart guide of ToolJet
I was trying to fork the Tooljet repo to run it in my local machine and try contribute and fix some issues. This is my first attempt trying to contribute to open source projects.
I ran the docker script in their README.md and was able to make it work in my local machine. Then, I tried to follow their Quickstart Guide to familiarize myself with the tool.
While doing the 2nd step of the guide, which is Create a Database Table, it showed me this error when I tried to create the table:
"The schema must be one of the following: public"
Error in the network tab
Is there anything that I missed while setting up the app in my local machine?
============================================================
I tried searching for similar cases when running Tooljet in the local machine. I found a similar issue here in stackover flow but I'm not sure what upgrade were they pertaining to in the conversation.
Thank in advance for the help and have a wonderful day!
